# How to clip a raster with a mask in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am trying to clip a raster using a virtual raster as mask layer in QGIS. It doesn't create a file. Could anyone explain how I should proceed to do that?

[image: printscreen]

Comment: This looks to be answered here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86960/clip-raster-layer-with-raster-mask-layer-in-qgis?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You need to have both files in the same CRS. To avoid trouble it is useful to set the map canvas to the same CRS as well.