# Batch Processing and Raster Calculators in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, saga

As of right now I have two sets of raster files. The first and second set are of differing sizes. I am attempting to use set to clip the other, using the process outlined in this question here [Clipping raster layer with *raster* mask layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86960/clip-raster-layer-with-raster-mask-layer-in-qgis) (the one that says you can "create a unitary mask on the fly ")

This process works. However, the QGIS raster calculator is unable to use batch processing, and my understanding of the GDAL calculator is it can only be used on similarly sized raster files. I have attempted to use the SAGA raster calculator, but I am unable to get any kind of equation that works.

What equation would I need to use in the SAGA raster calculator to produce similar results and, if this is not possible, what other QGIS specific options do I have?

Comment: Different sizes in terms of extent or pixel dimensions? In either case [gdalwarp](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html)) is your friend. You need to align your rasters to one another. So choose one of the sets of rasters (I assume the rasters in each individual "set" share the same dimensions and pixel sizes?) and set them to the extent and pixel size of the other. You'll then have the 2 sets of rasters which now sit on top of one another. That should then allow you to run your raster algebra as required in any software really.

Comment: @PolyGeo QGIS has different raster calculators available. It has the "QGIS Raster Calculator" and the GDAL and SAGA Raster Calculator which are available as processing tools. Therefore the question is about QGIS, so I am voting to reopen.

Comment: @mtn You can run the QGIS Raster Calculator as batch process if you start it from processing tools and not via Raster-Menu (at least from 3.4 upwards, dont have an older version by hand).

Comment: @MrXsquared I should have said "Please decide which of the QGIS raster calculators (native,GDAL or SAGA) do you wish to ask about in this particular question".  Including that detail would focus the question sufficiently for me to vote to re-open too.  Otherwise, it still seems like two questions currently.